# Unique attribute among different element types

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to add a uniqueness constraint on an attribute shared by different element types. All these elements share a set of common attributes, defined using an `attributeGroup`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:attributeGroup name="commonAttributes">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="displayName" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  ...
  <xs:element name="mainType" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"></xs:attributeGroup>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="secondType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"></xs:attributeGroup>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ...
</xs:schema>
```

Basically, both `firstType` and `secondType` elements define the `id` attribute, which needs to have unique values accross each `mainType` instance. From what I've read, the `unique` constraint cannot be set inside a `xs:attributeGroup`. Setting this constraint on the `firstType` and `secondType` elements would obviously work only among other elements of that type, meaning that an instance of a `firstType` element could have the same `id` value as a `secondType` element.

Is there a way of making the `id` attribute unique among all types defined inside the `mainType` element? Having a single and setting the current element name as attributes would imply significant code changes and an implicit change of specs (which I'd very much like not to trigger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` (or `firstType | secondType`) as an XPath expression.

Try this:

```
        <xs:unique name="uniqueAttr">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"></xs:field>
        </xs:unique>
```

Use the above code inside your `mainType` element, like the following:

```
 <xs:element name="mainType" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="firstType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"></xs:attributeGroup>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="secondType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"></xs:attributeGroup>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueAttr">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"></xs:field>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. The main thing to take from this is that XPath helps abstract the different element types. The `*` means "all children", regardless of their node name.